# Composition with multiple params

Tags: purescript

I quite often find myself in a need to use point-free functional compositon for functions with multiple params with methods like that:

```
compose2 :: ∀ a b c r. (c -> r) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> r
compose2 g f a b = g (f a b)


compose3 :: ∀ a b c d r. (d -> r) -> (a -> b -> c -> d) -> a -> b -> c -> r
compose3 g f a b c = g (f a b c)
```

I see no standard lib offering such methods directly, are there some other more simple means to get the same result?

Comment: maybe if you give some examples on how you use them we might be able to offer an alternative (you asked for other means) - *simple* is a difficult concept though

Comment: When I have a function with two/three args and I want to map the result of it. I think use cases are obvious from signatures. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Searching on Pursuit by your type signatures](https://pursuit.purescript.org/search?q=%28c+-%3E+r%29+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+b+-%3E+c%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+b+-%3E+r) reveals [a library called `purescript-point-free`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-point-free/0.1.3/docs/PointFree) that offers both `compose2` and `compose3`, operator aliases for them, and many more.

Comment: I've seen this package, but is not standard, do you use it? How are you dealing with the described problem in OP?

Comment: I don't have this problem. How do you define "standard"?

Comment: Supported by core/contrib teams, recommended for use.

Comment: By that definition of "standard" - no, I'm afraid there is no standard library for this. The PureScript core team is small and poorly (if at all) funded, so the only libraries that end up "standard" by your definition are the ones that support the compiler itself or the ones that most of community depends on. As for "recommended for use" - well, I do recommend it. Does that count? ;-)